# How to update record using id in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am new in `Node Js` and trying to learn it. I am currently follow this tutorial: http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/ but its incomplete.

I want, if I click on any user from the list of users, it will take me to new page and show the record in form for update. I don't know how to send data onclick, find the record from the db and show it inside a form to update.

Here is the index file with all the functions:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/*Get Hello world page*/
router.get('/helloword', function(req, res){

    res.render("Helloworld", {title:'Hello, World!'});
});

/*Get UserList*/
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res){
    var db = req.db;
    var collection =db.get('usercollection');
    collection.find({}, {}, function(e, docs){
        res.render('userlist',{
            "userlist": docs
        });
    });
});

/*Get New User Page*/
router.get('/newuser', function(req, res){
    res.render('newuser',{title: 'Add New User'})
});

/* POST to Add User Service */
router.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {

    // Set our internal DB variable
    var db = req.db;

    // Get our form values. These rely on the "name" attributes
    var userName = req.body.username;
    var userEmail = req.body.useremail;

    // Set our collection
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');

    // Submit to the DB
    collection.insert({
        "username" : userName,
        "email" : userEmail
    }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            // If it failed, return error
            res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
        }
        else {
            // And forward to success page
            res.redirect("userlist");
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Thanks in advance please help me for guidance

Comment: Can you show the client-side code?

Comment: Your question is about front end development, not node.js. First test your POST with https://www.getpostman.com/docs if that works, then start the front end form

Comment: @Mark, i am already posted the index.js file. rest files is ejs files

Comment: No @EdwardKnowles , i want to create a function for select particular id record and update it on submit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use `findAndModify` ([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/))

Using your code you could implement an update route like so.

```
router.post('/user/:userId', function (req, res) {

    // Set our internal DB variable
    var db = req.db;

    // Get our form values. These rely on the "name" attributes
    var userName = req.body.username;
    var userEmail = req.body.useremail;

    // Set our collection
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');

    collection.findAndModify(
            {_id: req.query.userId}, // query
            [['_id', 'asc']],  // sort order
            {
                $set: {
                    "username": userName,
                    "email": userEmail
                }
            }, // replacement
            {}, // options
            function (err, object) {
                if (err) {
                    console.warn(err.message);  // returns error if no matching object found
                } else {
                    console.dir(object);
                }
            });

});
```

However this does not have any validation to make sure that the user has the correct permissions to update this, make sure you add something like the query

`{$and: [{_id: req.query.userId}, {createdBy: req.user}]}`